# Create a fitness run with the Open Graph API in iOS without GPS-data

Tags: ios, facebook, gps, facebook-opengraph

I want to share a fitness run via the Open Graph API.

For me it is most important to display the distance and the duration in the top line of the post right beside the name of the user, along with a description text. (So maybe my idea to use the fitness:runs action instead of a custom action is wrong?)

I tried several solutions from StackOverflow, but none of them use the 'FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction' with the 'FBSDKShareDialog', so I modified it a bit. This is my code so far:

```
// Create the object
NSDictionary *courseDict = @{
                             @"og:type": @"fitness:course",
                             @"og:title": @"Run",
                             @"og:description": @"Run",
                             @"fitness:duration:value": @"300",
                             @"fitness:duration:units": @"s",
                             @"fitness:distance:value": @"1.2",
                             @"fitness:distance:units": @"km",
                             @"fitness:speed:value": @"13.2",
                             @"fitness:speed:units": @"m/s",

                             @"fitness:metrics:location:latitude": @"37.51769",
                             @"fitness:metrics:location:longitude": @"126.9908",
                             @"fitness:metrics:location:altitude": @"13.85767",
                             @"fitness:metrics:timestamp": @"2011-01-26T00:30"
                             };

FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *course = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:courseDict];

// Create the action
FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
action.actionType = @"fitness:runs";
[action setObject:course forKey:@"course"];

// Create the content
FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
content.action = action;
content.previewPropertyName = @"course";

[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:viewController
                             withContent:content
                                delegate:self];
```

Every time I want to share this I get the Error Code 102. I double checked the App name and everything else and I can still share any other custom OG Stories via the app, so I assume the code above is the problem.

What am I missing? Is the url property of the course required to get it working?

Comment: Try making these changes and see if it works: @"og:type": @"fitness.course",
action.actionType = @"fitness.runs";
[action setObject:course forKey:@"fitness:course"];
content.previewPropertyName = @"fitness:course";